# Failed to restore .csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I am updating my project's Microsoft.Graph package to the most recent version 5.11.0
(I am using Visual Studio Code, .NET Core v6, C#)
After updating from Microsoft.Graph -v4.48.0 to -v 5.11.0, when I try running the Debugger tool, I get the log: Failed to restore .csproj

I have tried uninstalling my C# Extension in VS Code and reinstalling it, as well as closing/restarting VS Code.

The version of Microsoft.Graph.Core I am using is 2.0.14 (This is the only version that doesn't cause additional errors in my code).

Given the recent updates to these packages, I'm assuming this is a version constraint, but the most recent versions of each package remove methods needed for my task calls.